# How to Receive click location from another process with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, console

My C# application needs to receive a click position from another process, I then need to show on my app. But I don't know how I would implement it.

Could someone help me figure out how to do this?

Thanks so much

Comment: edit your question. It will hopefully be received better. What do you want to do, console, wpf or winforms!?

Comment: what is that `another process`?

Comment: Sorry , I work with WPF app but I think someone know in other app.

Another process is activating process but user can choose process to receive position.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achive

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called a "Hook".  Windows allows you to hook both the keyboard and mouse events.  Basically windows works by injecting the appropriate movements and clicks of the mouse (and keys typed) into the application that has focus.

However using the hook, you receive all of the events, not just those relevant to your app.  Once you have the hook established you can then do what you want with the information.

Note that you are going down to the windows OS and if you do the wrong thing here, you can leak the handles and you can also cause windows to get into a bad state.

There is a great tutorial [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) from MS Technet that describes how to do this in C#.